# Players can't jump well

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am able to move player referring to this YouTube video.
[FIRST PERSON MOVEMENT in Unity - FPS Controller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc)

However, when a player jumps, if the direction of travel is a wall, the player cannot jump well.
[like this](https://gfycat.com/insidiouslikableamethystgemclam)

If I jump from a distance, I can jump onto the wall.

Camera Script:

```
public float mouseSensitivity;

[SerializeField]
Transform playerBody = default;

float xRotation = 0f;

private void Start()
{ 
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

void Update()
{
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    xRotation -= mouseY;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
    playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
}
```

Movement Script:

```
[SerializeField]
CharacterController CharacterController = default;

[SerializeField]
LayerMask groundMask = default;
[SerializeField]
Transform groundCheck = default;
float groundDistance = 0.4f;
bool isGrounded = false;

public float playerSpeed;
public float playerGravity;
public float playerJumpSpeed;

Vector3 velocity;

private void Update()
{
    isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

    if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        velocity.y = -2f;

    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

    CharacterController.Move(move * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(playerJumpSpeed * -2f * playerGravity);
    }

    velocity.y += playerGravity * Time.deltaTime;

    CharacterController.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Please tell me someone

Comment: Please provide code or other information that can help someone to solve your issue. Your question as-is is better suited for the comments section of that YouTube video.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: You never initialized `playerJumpSpeed`, `playerGravity`, or `playerSpeed`. Try initializing those with various values (`3f`, `-9.81f`, and `12f` respectively are the values provided in the video so those are a good starting point).

Comment: Setting the jump height to 12 and setting the other numbers the same did not work. Only the vibration when it gets stuck gets bigger.

Comment: I told you to set the jump height to `3f`, the gravity to `-9.81f`, and the speed to `12f`. Also if you can't find a solution here maybe see if there is anything you can find over at [game dev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I set it up, but it didn't work. I will eventually use Rigidbody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting Step Offset of Character controller to 0 eliminated vibration. It can no longer walk on small steps, but now I can jump well.

Answer (score 0):

i think it has something to do with these lines.

if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        velocity.y = -2f;

Also check if the wall is on the ground mask because if it is it will be make the isGrounded be true which would be why it the player is falling like that

also i would recommend using a raycast instead of this:
isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is the Move() of the CharacterController an instantaneous move? It looks like it is stuck in the wall. It looks like a transform.position, not physical.

Comment: try to comment out the checksphere and see if it lets you jump properly